# Slots in CLOS

Tags: oop, common-lisp

Could any CL'er please explain 'slots' in CLOS? I am finding it difficult to understand the part after the slot name. That is in :

(defclass foo ()
 (data1 :initarg foo))

What do the 'initarg' and other such similar things mean? I am re-reading manuals. So, I would really appreciate if any of you here could explain it to a layman like me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is slightly wrong. It has to be:

```
(defclass foo ()
   ((data1 :initarg foo)))
```

Notice the added parentheses to indicate a list of slot descriptions.

DEFCLASS takes a list of slots. So with two slots we have:

```
(defclass foo ()
   ((data1 :initarg :data1arg
           :initform (random 1.0) 
           :type number
           :documentation "doc here"
           :accessor foo-data1-acc)
    (data2 :initarg :data2arg)))
```

DATA1 is the name of the slot. Behind that you find pairs of :keyword value.

:INITARG tells you what the parameter for MAKE-INSTANCE is.
    (make-instance 'foo :data1arg 10)   ; creates the object and sets the slot data1 to 10.
Usually you should use a keyword symbol (like :data1arg here).

:INITFORM sets the slot by default, when the object is created. Like in:
    (make-instance 'foo)   ; creates the object. The slot is set to the value of the initform.

:TYPE specifies the type of the slot's object.

:DOCUMENTATION is just a string for, well, documentation.

:ACCESSOR specifies a function to read and write the slot.

```
(foo-data1-acc some-foo-object-here)             ; read
(setf (foo-data1-acc some-foo-object-here) 7)    ; write
```

Note that you can write the pairs in any order and that you can also specify multiple accessor functions. There are also :READER and :WRITER functions.

With CLOS you can specify all that within the DEFCLASS macro. These things are not automatically generated like in defstruct, which has a shorter notation.

The description of DEFCLASS is here: [DEFCLASS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm).
[Short CLOS Intro](http://www.aiai.ed.ac.uk/~jeff/clos-guide.html).

Comment: In the description of :INITFORM,  should the slot data1 be set to 10 , or a random value from 0 too 1.0 ?

Comment: Yep, that was an error. Corrected above. When the initarg is not given, the initform is used to initialize the slot. I reality the mechanism is a bit more complicated, but often this is enough to know.

Answer (score 1):

In a slot specification, the general syntax is (*slot-name* [*slot-option* *option-value*]...). The essentially-authoritatiev reference is [the HyperSpec page on defclass](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm#defclass), but in short:

**:reader** A function to read the value of the slot
**:writer** A function to write the value of the slot
**:accessor** A function to both read and (via SETF) set the value of the slot
**:initarg** A symbol to set the slot's value from MAKE-INSTANCE

There are more, but that list is the four I mostly use (actually, I mostly use :initarg and one of :accessor or :reader).